# How to write loop that runs until function output matches a given value exactly

Tags: python

Edit: Thank you for the suggestions. I've updated the code in the hope that the actual problem is clearer now. My main issue is that it takes very long to compute and compare 1000s of values, and that I can't find any way to run the loop for every possible input value that could lead to a match.

I am comparing modelled to measured values using different inputs for the model. I want to find the input at which the model and the measured value are identical.

As an example of what I have so far:

```
import random 

inputs=np.linspace(0,5,100)
measured=np.linspace(0,10,100)

for i in measured:
   for j in inputs:
      model=random.randint(1,5)+j 

      if model==m:
          print(j)
          break
```

My problem: there is a huge range of possible input numbers so this is very slow. I'm not sure it's even possible to always get a match even if I use 10000 input numbers in the given range. I guess what I really want is for the loop through an infinite number of inputs until there is an exact match.
I haven't managed to get any matches from my real code so far since it's just running for hours.

I can't be the first person trying to do something like this, and there must be a faster and more elegant way of doing this? I would really appreciate any feedback, I'm sure I'm making some logic mistakes here too.

To describe the real data: the input is cloud concentration, the output of the function is an irradiance spectrum, and I want to compare this with a measured irradiance spectrum to find the cloud concentration at the time of measurement.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. This is critical for understanding python.

Comment: `if condition: break` is how you stop the loop when the condition is met.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: @Barmar I just used spaces now - hope that works! thanks for the tip using break!

Comment: Assigning `j` will not stop the loop. The next iteration simply reassigns it from the next value in the range, it doesn't care what the current value is. If you want to stop the loop, use `break`.

Comment: Maybe just explain what is the input and the desired output without looking at a specific way to get it yet (as the current way doesn't seem feasible in reasonable time anyway).

Comment: `for m in measured: for j in input: model = random.randint(1, 5) + j`

Comment: P.S. don't use `input` as a variable name. You're replacing the standard `input()` function.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, yes, even with the improvements from Barmar it still isn't working. The modelling function I use takes ~3 minutes per input so if I use this method with my actual data I'm looking at hundreds of hours. Sorry if anything in my description was unclear - the input is cloud concentration, the output of the function is an irradiance spectrum, and I want to compare this with a measured irradiance spectrum to find the cloud concentration at the time of measurement.

Comment: I think this would need a more mathematical/algorithmic solution based on properties of the function that calculates the spectrum from the cloud concentration (continuous, monotonic, linear,... connection of some components of input and output).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can just use `break` instruction instead of that

```
for i in range (0, len(measured)):
   m=measured[i]
   for j in range (0, len(input)):
      model=random.randint(1,5)+input[j] 

      if model==m:
          print(input[j])
          break
```

`break` instruction only stops the last nested loop

Answer (score 0):

- You need to use `break` to discontinue a loop.
- It isn't necessary to use a ranged loop. You can get the values directly, and should.
- `input` is a python built-in. You should choose a different designator.

```py
for spectrum in measured:
    for value in inputs:
        model = random.randint(1,5) + value 

        # break `value` loop
        if model == spectrum:
            print(value)
            break
```

If you end up needing indexes for some reason, still do not use a ranged loop. Use `enumerate`.

```py
for i, spectrum in enumerate(measured):
    for j, value in enumerate(inputs):
        model = random.randint(1,5) + value 

        # break `value` loop
        if model == spectrum:
            print(value)
            break
```

[Why use enumerate() instead of range()](https://themeptation.medium.com/why-use-enumerate-instead-of-range-in-your-pythons-loops-d33bfd9c7531)

broad gist of link:

- numbers should be ranged (ex: find all prime numbers between 0 and 200)
- "things" should be enumerated if you need the index (ex: iterate over fruit names)

In your case `inputs` and `measured` are "things", even though they contain numbers. This is because your range is used to index the next "thing". You can do that without the range.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's very helpful. But I think I wouldn't want to break both loops if I got a match, just the inner one and then move on to the next measured spectrum!

Comment: @protoperidinium - I adjusted my answer to fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

```
import random 

input=np.linspace(0,5,100)
measured=np.linspace(0,10,100)

for i in range (0, len(measured)):
   m=measured[i]
   for j in range (0, len(input)):
      model=random.randint(1,5)+input[j] 

      if model==m:
          print(input[j])
          j=len(input)
```

Bad code, applying formatting fixes and style fixes yields the proceeding.

```
flag = False
while flag:
    for i in range(0, len(measured)):
        m = measured[i]
        for j in range(0, len(input)):
            model=random.randint(1,5)+input[j] 
            flag = model == m
print(input[j])
#j=len(input)
```

This seems to be a bad misunderstanding, this will be immediately reset in your version. Python for loop runs through a collection.

Ultimately if you want exactly a match, it could take a while, but you need to restructure to exit the loop.

NOTE: break is required if you want to only cancel the work on the j loop.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for everybody's suggestions. They were really helpful in improving my code. I finally came up with an approach that seems to work to approach a match iteratively (it's clunky):

```
import random 

inputs=np.linspace(0.00001,5,5)
measured=np.linspace(0,10,100)

for i in measured:
   for j in inputs:
      ri=random.randint(1,5)
      model=ri+j
      if model==m:
          print(j)
          break
      if model-0.5*model<=m<=model+0.5*model
          inputs_2=np.linspace(j*0.75,j*1.25,5)
          for k in inputs_2:
              model=radiation_function(k)
              if model==m:
                  print(k)
                  break
              if model-0.4*model<=m<=model+0.4*model
                  inputs_3=np.linspace(k*0.75,k*1.25,5)
                  for l in inputs_3:
                  model=radiation_function(l)
                  if model==m:
                      print(l)
                      break
                  if model-0.3*model<=m<=model+0.3*model
                      print(str(l)+"approximate match")
                      break
#or continue with nested loops
```

Sorry if my question was in any way unclear, and thanks to everybody who answered. Every answer and comment was helpful. However, I couldn't see any working suggestions for improving the actual function of the loop, which was iterating through model inputs until the model output matched a given value, when the possible range of inputs is very large.

I think that my approach here is also very slow, but will save some time by starting with a small number of possible inputs to loop through and zoning in on the best match, rather than going through all 10000 possible inputs in order. One problem with my approach is that if the first output is within the range I give in the if statement, it will progress into the next nested loop, without knowing that the next output within the first loop could be even closer.

I'd be very happy though about suggestions of improvement or better approaches. Thanks!